# How to return return data with Ionic sqlite

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I an ionic program that uses sqlite to store data. When i return the data to the view, it returns nothing.

I have a service set up to fetch the data. It looks like

```
read(){
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: DB_NAME,
      location: 'default'
    })
    .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {  
      db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(32), datetime VARCHAR(32))', {})
        .then(() => console.log("Created Table OR NOT"))
        .catch(e => this.presentAlert(e));

      db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM todos ORDER BY id DESC', {})
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.rows.length > 0){
          for(var i=0; i < response.rows.length; i++){
            this.my_todos.push({
              id:response.rows.item(i).id, 
              name:response.rows.item(i).name, 
              datetime:response.rows.item(i).datetime
            })
          }
        }       
        //this.presentAlert(JSON.stringify(this.my_todos));
        return this.my_todos;
      })
      .catch(e => this.presentAlert(JSON.stringify(e)));
    })
    .catch(e => this.presentAlert(JSON.stringify(e)));
  }
```

On the home.ts file, i try to access the service like

```
this.todos = this.todoService.read()
```

When i log `this.todos` on my console. It doesn't return anything. Can anyone please help me?...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50667665/1816437

Comment: Wow, thanks for replying me. I saw the post. I tried to implement what you said but i can't seem to get it right. Also, the return function is a type 'void' not a promise.

Comment: You don't return your data, add `return sqlite.create().then(()=> { return db.executeSql(...); }});`

Comment: If that doesn't work I can give you a workaround but it's quite a nasty one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//Hi,
//You cannot do this this.todos = this.todoService.read().
//You should write promises to get data from sqlite and use them in your //component.
//I expect read function is in the service file(todoService.ts). Change it like //this.

```js
//Hi,
//You cannot do this this.todos = this.todoService.read().
//You should write promises to get data from sqlite and use them in your //component.
//I expect read function is in the service file(todoService.ts). Change it like //this.
```

```js
    public read() {
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
var db = new SQLite();
        
        var query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(32), datetime VARCHAR(32))";
        db.create({
          name: "data.db",
          location: "default"
        }).then((db1: SQLiteObject) => {
          db1.executeSql(query,[])
          .then((res) => {
            let todos = [];
            if(res.rows.length > 0 ) {
              todos.push(res.rows.item(0))
            }
            resolve(todos)
          },(error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
})

}
//  The promise returns an array of objects


In the page component 
// declare this
 public itemList : Array<Object>;
// In the constructor
this.itemList = [];

this.todoService.read().then((result) => {
this.itemList = <Array<Object>> result;
// you will get the retrieved data from sqlite from this array
console.log(this.itemList)
})
)


// This should work Please update me in case of any issues
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks alot. I do have one more little problem though. On the view, the items duplicate when ever i refresh or change pages... Please do you know why?

Comment: Please can you elaborate your problem

Comment: My HomePage is where i show the list of todos. It looks something like `*ngFor="let todo of itemList"` The list shows all right but when ever i go to another page, lets say i go to the page where i add a new Todo when the process is done and i set page back to root. The list of todos i have duplicate themselves. If i exit the app and open it again everything comes back to normal. I read about it somewhere but i am not exactly sure of the details, the person said it had to do with subscribing and unsubscribing. Does any of that make sense? Thanks for your assistance.